# Given the result, follow de sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am trying to figure out several sequences about simple numbers.

Given simple sequences following x^2 T times.

`2^2(6 times) => 
002 004 008 016 032 064`

`3^2(5 times) =>
003 009 027 081 243`

Then, I have to transform it into a sequence of sums of the previous numbers.

`2 4 8 16 32 64`
become
`2 6 14 30 62 126`

My question is: Given a sum of a sequence and the T(times), how to I figure out(GENERIC WAY) the x from x^2?

Example:
Given `126` as the sum of the sequence, knowing it was interacted `6 times`, what is the `x^2` `6 times` in sequence, and then summed all the number, gives as result 126.

Answer: `2`.

Times:

`1 2 3 4 5 6 7`

Sequence `2^2` 7 times:

`2 4 8 16 32 64`

Sum:

`2 + 4 + 8 + 16 + 32 + 64 => 126`

Comment: Nice question! Do you know anything about "geometric series" (geometric sequences, geometric progressions)? If not, look them up, and see if you can work out how they relate to your question.

Comment: "Sequence 2^2 6 times" doesn't make sense. You mean either "Sequence of 6 iterates of the function $x\mapsto2x$" or "First 6 terms of the sequence 2^n".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is, given $n$ and also $$k=a+a^2+...+a^n,$$ find the value of the initial term $a$.
The sum on the right is $$k=\frac{a^{n+1}-a}{a-1},$$ so that you seek the solution(s) to
$$a^{n+1}-(k+1)a+k=0.$$
If the given $n$ is 2 or more this is at least a cubic equation, and somewhat difficult to solve directly.

Provided the sequences are integers, you could use that $a$ is a factor of $k$, and so search for the solution $a$ among the factors of $k$.

EDIT: Actually 1 is a solution of the equation, and you could rule that out easily since if $a=1$ then $n=k$. On factoring out $x-a$ one just arrives back at the original equation $$k=a+a^2+...+a^n,$$ which is of degree $n$ and also difficult to solve directly.